# Layout problems with Drupal 8 (beginner!)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, drupal, drupal-8

I’m learning Drupal 8, HTML and CSS.

I recently migrated our Drupal 7 site to a Drupal 8 site.
https://eerr.org.uk/ (Drupal 7 site)
http://d8-dev.eerr.org.uk/ (Drupal 8 site)

I’m having problems getting simple things like the text to line up.  Some things seemed to be controlled in Drupal (Appearance > Settings ).  Others I guess I need to change the CSS files.

I’m using a barrio theme based on bootstrap 4.

I’d like to get the Logo left justified with the other headings (as it is on the original site), can someone help me out explaining how to do this ?

I think it needs to be within the div with the container class but I don’t see how to easily change that.

I was able to to put the nav bar in the container in Drupal settings:
Appearance > Settings > Components > Navbar Structure
Tick: Navbar width container
Check if navbar width will be inside container or fluid width.

Mark

Comment: If you put it inside a container, it will look like this: https://nimb.ws/exgNGf

Comment: Thanks @m4n0 I did manage to get things to line up by hacking around in developer tools as well.  Obviously when I reload the brower the changes are gone! :). Maybe my inital quesiton is too open.  I'm trying to find out how I make the changes in terms of Drupal.  Do I make it in the configuraiton or do I need to edit CSS / HTML ?  and is this default bootstrap-4 behavior ?

Comment: You will have to edit the Drupal header file. 75% of the cases. But check with a Drupal expert on how to override it. I can get you a CSS solution but that would not be a Drupal standard. A hacky way but.